# form field in jsp not change java variable

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, backend

I can't change the data information in my jsp page when I submit the form and call a java function(When the button is pressed).

This is a peace of code used in my .jsp form field:

```
...
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
<h:outputLabel for="contactName" value="#{msj.contactName}"/>
<h:inputText id="contactName" value="#{CustodiaBean.name}" required="true">
<f:validator validatorId = "TextValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="contactName" styleClass="errorMessage" style="color:red"/>

<h:outputLabel for="contactLastName" value="#{msj.contactLastName}"/>
<h:inputText id="contactLastName" value="#{CustodiaBean.last_name}" required="true" >
<f:validator validatorId = "TextValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="contactLastName" styleClass="errorMessage" style="color:red"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<div id="button">
<h:commandLink styleClass="hoveringLink3doubleGreen" action="#{CustodiaBean.updateAccount}">
<h:outputText id="save_button" value="#{msj.save_changes}"/>
</h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink styleClass="hoveringLink3double" action="myAccountCustodia">
<h:outputText id="cancel_button" value="#{msj.cancel}"/>
</h:commandLink>
</div>
</h:form>
...
```

This is the same piece of code used in other pages like login and register user.
The form fields get the current values in "CustodiaBean", but i try to change the value in the form and when I press the button to check the value(call a function in "CustodiaBean"), I always get the previous value (The new form value is not changed in my class "CustodiaBean").

I'm using a tomcat server and eclipse.

Is necesary to force the field to be bloqued and save the changes when the button is pressed??

I don't know why this is happen. Can anyone help me or give me some advice??

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Obviously you're using a framework because `<h:` tags aren't standard JSP. So please tag the framework. Or is it JSF?

Comment: It`s a jsf within jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

Does h:inputText etc also has a property name? Try to see what html is generated. It may be possible that your data is not getting submitted properly. Any HTML form directly submit feilds which are non disabled with the name property of each field. IF id is present and not name, it wont be submitted correctly. Try debugging at browser level or via some firefox plugin like tamper data.

Hope it helps